# Nginx 404 for js and css file

Tags: php, nginx

I am beginner programmer. I have small problem with Nginx.

I have this configuration sites-available/domain.conf:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  name.eu;
    root /data/www/test/cs/;
    client_max_body_size 50M;
    index index.php;
    disable_symlinks off;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    location /api/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /api.php?$query_string;
    }

    location /wypas2/ {
        include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        sub_filter_once off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Connection '';
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_cache off;
        proxy_pass_header Content-Type;
        proxy_pass http://name2.eu;
    }

    location ~ \.css {
        add_header  Content-Type    text/css;
    }

    location ~ \.js {
        expires max;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
        add_header  Content-Type    application/x-javascript;
    }
 location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 240;
    }
raylog2_json;
    #error_log  syslog:server=eis-wixa:12305;
}
```

when i open my domain I have 404 form css and js :( Html is work fine.

How can i repair it?

Comment: Can add  a screendump / text of the file structure of `/data/www/test/cs/`?